# Подскажите, почему возникает ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо, чтобы ф-ия удаляла букву 'o' в слове world. Подскажите, почему возникает ошибка в коде?

```js
window.document.write(disemvowel('world'));
  function disemvowel(str){
    let a=[''];
    a=str;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       if(a[i]=='o'){
         a.splice(i,1);
       }
    }
    return a;
  }
```

Comment: Потому что надо знать синтаксис языка. `let a = str.split(""); for( let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )...; return a.join("");` - - цикл с конца, чтобы не было проблем с индексами после удаления элемента из массива. А вообще, `function myFunc(str){ return str.replace(/[aeiouy]/ig,""); }` - называется "регулярное выражение".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что это строка, а не массив. Строки неизменяемые и у них нет метода splice.

```js
document.write(disemvowel('world'));

function disemvowel(str) {
  let a = [...str];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 'o') {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  return a.join('');
}
```

А вообще, надо делать так:

```js
console.log('world'.replace(/o/g, ''));
console.log('world'.split('o').join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так еще можно

```
function disemvowel(str,symbol){
    return str.replace(symbol,'');
  }
```

Comment: Так себе. `"abacaba".replace("b", "")`.

Comment: Тогда `replace( new RegExp( symbol, "ig" ), "" )`